# double-click on cell formula in protected sheet activates sheet to which formula points

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have a workbook with two worksheets in it.

I protect sheet2 via following code:
    
    `Sub test()
        Worksheets(2).Cells.Locked = True
        Worksheets(2).Protect DrawingObjects:=False
    End sub`

(I've set DrawingObjects:=False because I still want to be able to edit forms)

Protection does what I expect it to on sheet2 and when I double-click a cell it displays the warning "The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet. To make a change, unprotect the sheet. You might be requested to enter a password.".

However, if the double-clicked cell contains for example a SUM formula, it highlights the range to which the formula refers to. If it's a SUMIFS formula that refers to ranges in sheet1, it activates sheet1.

Any ideas on how this can be prevented without disabling double-clicking?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When protecting the worksheet, you just need to ***uncheck*** the option to

> *Allow all users of this worksheet to:* `Select locked cells`
>
> > [image: img]

---

The VBA equivalent is:

```
ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
```

---

There are **three options** for enabling cell selection:

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Lock or unlock specific areas of a protected worksheet**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a)
- MSDN : [**`Worksheet.EnableSelection` Property** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-enableselection-property-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Worksheet.Protect` Method** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Protection` Object** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/protection-object-excel)

---

## Edit:

To allow users to select cells (and see the contents) but **disallow double-clicking** specifically, you could ***check*** the option for `Select locked cells` and then add code to the **Worksheet Module**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

(To open the *Worksheet Module*, right click the worksheet's tab at the bottom of the screen and choose `View Code`.)

Note that users will still be able to edit the cell's formula in (and therefore outline the cell range included in the formula) by clicking in the formula bar or pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> after selecting the cell (although [the formula bar can be removed](https://ccm.net/faq/9745-how-to-show-or-hide-the-formula-bar-in-excel) as well.)

Comment: Thanks. Any way to still be able to click on the cells but prevent Excel from highlighting/ activating formula references?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand: you want users to be able to select cells but not see or change the contents?

Comment: I want users to be able to select cells and see the contents but I don't want Excel to activate another sheet or highlight ranges in the same sheet.

Comment: I added explanation of how to disable double-clicking in the worksheet.

Comment: So you want the users to be able to ***edit forms*** and ***see** (but not edit) **formulas*** but ***not*** see the cell outlines for the formulas they're looking at.  Can I ask why?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! We are temporarily using the forms to send comments to each other. In the final version of the file there will be no forms. The reason I wanted users to be able to select formulas without being able to see cell outlines was to mimic pdf behavior where one can still copy values and paste them elsewhere. I guess I could live with 'anything can be selected' if it were not to display another sheet...

Comment: If you want to mimic PDF behaviour why not save the file as a PDF?